# Has anyone used Robotium or Calculon for testing Android apps?

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, acceptance-testing

Has anyone used Robotium or Calculon for testing Android apps?  Are they useful? Any recommendations on which is better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd go with Robotium since Calculon is still in very early stages. Here's a comment from Calculon's author:

> Well, currently it’s just a bunch of source files which I pulled out of another project...Note that this library is still a very
>   early prototype. Its API will probably
>   change. [Source](http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/introducing-calculon-a-java-dsl-for-android-activity-testing/#comment-769)

I've played with Robotium today, it definitely makes writing functional tests fun. To give you an idea, here are a few method highlights from the API:

- clickOnButton, clickOnText
- enterText
- getCurrentButtons, getCurrentEditTexts, getCurrentImageViews, getCurrentSpinners, getCurrentTextViews
- pressMenuItem, pressSpinnerItem
- searchText, searchEditText, searchButton

Here is a code sample from the Getting Started Guide:

```
  public void testTextIsSaved() throws Exception {
    solo.clickOnText("Other");
    solo.clickOnButton("Edit");
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("Edit Window"));
    solo.enterText(1, "Some text for testing purposes")
    solo.clickOnButton("Save");
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("Changes have been made successfully"));
    solo.clickOnButton("Ok");
    assertTrue(solo.searchText("Some text for testing purposes"));}
```

Definitely give it a try if you're going to write **ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2** classes. Check out the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started) guide for instructions.